# The median in a isosceles triangle is ortoghonal into a hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces

how can I prove that if $p$, $q$, $r$ and $o$ are points in a Hilbert space such that $p$, $q$, $o$ are collinear,  $\|p-o\|=\|q-o\|$ and $\|p-r\|=\|q-r\|$ then $r-o \perp p-o$?.

I think it's a simple count but I can't do, can anybody help me?

Comment: Begin with  
$$\|p-r\|^2 =\| (p-o)+(o-r)\|^2=\|p-o\|^2+\|o-r\|^2 + 2\langle p-o,o-r\rangle$$ Then write down the same for $\|q-r\|^2$, and compare the formulas. Also recall that $p-o= - (q-o)$.